# Prevent DDOS on websocket server nodejs

Tags: node.js, security

I have a app which lets yoy keep your notes at a single place its realtime bw all the devices you are logged in I am using a nodejs wesocket it was working fine but a recently i found out someone was sending a huge amount of requests to my websocket server. He sent a large amount of data through websockets to my mongodb and the data was sent just for the purpose of taking the app down (useless crap data just had 'aaaaa')

What i want is prevent those clients from using the websockets who are making more than 10requests per minute.

Comment: This is called DDOS, not brute force.  You're looking for CloudFlare.

Comment: Can't we do it directly from my server? Cloudflare doesn't provides custom ssl support in free plan

Comment: [This example](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#websocket-single-connection-prevent-flooding) with `rate-limiter-flexible` package should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments its better to go with services like `CloudFlare`, but for your specific use case (to implement directly on server) you should look at ways to **rate limit** the requests.

Here is an example of an library to rate limit `web-sockets` in `node`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws-rate-limit

Comment: Perfectly what i was looking for